# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'), my react app is not opening in my phone, but working in my pc

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

```
{this.state.articles.map((element) => {
     return <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
            <NewsItems title={element.title ? element.title : ""} description={element.description                     ? element.description : ""} imageurl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} author=    {!element.author ? "Unknown" : element.author} date={element.publishedAt} />
             </div>
 })}
```

When I'm trying to open my react app in my phone on that time there shows "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')".

But when i'm trying to open my react app in my pc, it works properly.

Comment: Try to debug with printing what is the value of `this.state.articles` first, and trace where the value being modified (where setState is called).